# Need help understanding Importing Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm reading the documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import), and I have a few questions. Just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding what this terminal command is **supposed** to do.

Question 1:

I have an SQLite .db file on my local computer. With this command, I can convert this db into a `mydb.dump` file, which I can then import into Heroku Postgres. Is this intepretation correct? If so, we can move on to my second question.

Question 2:

Attempting to run `PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump` is causing me some issues. From what I can understand, the values I'm supposed to substitute are

mypassword (heroku postgres password)

myuser (I have no idea what's supposed to be here)

mydb (name of db)

mydb.dump (name of dump)

What exactly should go into each of these values, and where can I find them?

Comment: SQLite and PostgreSQL are very different databases. What is the exact command you're trying to use to convert your SQLite file to something that Postgres can ingest? (As a side note I _**strongly**_ recommend switching to Postgres locally. Running different database systems in development and production is asking for trouble.)

Comment: `PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`

Comment: The `pg_dump` command is for dumping a _PostgreSQL_ database. It has nothing to do with SQLite. I'm still confused about how you're trying to convert an SQLite file to a Postgres-compatible database dump.

Comment: It seems my interpretation of the documentation was wrong. Thanks, If your previous comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pg_dump` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) dumps a *PostgreSQL* database. It has nothing to do with SQLite.

SQLite and PostgreSQL are very different databases. If you're going to use Postgres in production I strongly recommend using it in development as well. In general, your development environment (and any others, like a staging environment) should be as similar as possible to your production environment.

Comment: Indeed, I'm currently in the process of migrating everything to Postgres. Thanks.